# SSH on port 443 with SSLH

Tags: ssh, https

I have a problem with SSH and HTTPS on port 443.
I have installed [SSLH](http://www.rutschle.net/tech/sslh.shtml) on my VirtualServer an want to connect via Port 443 to SSH and also use 443 for the HTTPS server.

With my windows computer it will worked. But if i try to connect to the SSH via port 443 with my mac i get the following error:

```
AppDevTimeMachine:logs macuser$ ssh DOMAINVSERVER -p 443 -vvv
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to DOMAINVSERVER [IPVSERVER] port 443.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/macuser/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/macuser/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/macuser/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/macuser/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Comment: you can't use the same port on the same IP address for both `sshd` and a web server at the same time.  Only one can listen on the IP:port at a time.

Comment: I have installed SSLH. With SSLH web server and SSH will work over port 443. With windows it works. But not with my mac.

Comment: ah, right.  i suggest you add a link to unusual tools like that rather than just mention them by name. not many people will know what SSLH is. ... done.... i've added the link for you.

Comment: Get stuffs lile Wireshark and/or tcpdump ready. I remember that SSLH uses some matching on the header of the TCP packages but I guess it may miss something.

Answer (score 0):

maybe a problem related to corrupted fingerprint / keys

The fingerprints or the keys has corrupted (did you manually edit one of these files?). Remove the server-side fingerprint (in the clients): ~/.ssh/known_hosts and try again. 
When you re-connect you will be prompted to accept the host key again.

If you are able to access the machine you may want to make a copy and re-create the server-side ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.

Then you have to restart sshd

[EDIT] maybe a hosts.allow problem? inspect the file in the server to see il sshd is allowed for all sources
grep sshd /etc/hosts.allow
sshd: ALL

Comment: I have remove the server-side fingerprint in the clients and set sshd: ALL in hosts.allow. But it dont work. The "authorized_keys" is empty on the vServer. I dont connect via SSH Key i connect via password to ssh. On windows it works but on mac it dont work..

Comment: did you generate a new key on the mac, or copy the key from windows?

Comment: Do you find any information in mac's /var/log/system.log ?